# Is it possible to query a DDB table from Account A with EMR Hive in Account B?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I have an AWS account A with an EMR cluster with Hive set up.
I have an AWS account B with DynamodDB tables.

Is it possible to query the DynamoDB tables from account B with Hive in account A?
I know that you can easily query tables locally but how would you do it cross-account? Is it even possible? Or is there an alternative?